# Change value of primary key on other table

Tags: php, mysql

I have question about changing value in child table automatically if value of table mother change value.

I have two tables are `brand`(mother) and `cat`(child).

I add `foreign key` is `brand_id` in table `cat` related to primary key `id` in table `brand`.

If I change `brand_name` from `brand` table, I also want `brand_name` in table `cat` changed automatically. Is it possible? and how can I do it.

Thank you so much.

```
Brand:
```

[image]

```
Cat:
```

[image]

Comment: There should be no `brand_name` in your `cat` table, get the name from the related (`brand_id`) brand

Comment: Thank @kerbholz but my client want to see it. Is possible with function in mysql?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom trigger on the brand table which before update would perform the necessary updates on the cat table.

Here is a link to the documentation for MySQL triggers:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html

UPDATE:
As commented by @kerbholz, proper data modeling would suggest that the brand name column shouldn't exist in the cat column as it creates duplication of data. If this is purely for your client to see the data, perhaps building them a custom view using properly modeled tables is a better solution.

Link to appropriate documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you explain me by example syntax? I add in mysql but 'definition' is?

Comment: In the links there are examples of the proper syntax.

Comment: I understand adding brand_name in cat table is duplication of data but they gave me the available data so I want to keep it

Comment: That is exactly why I think giving your users a custom view of the data would be better for both of you. From your side, you get to maintain good data modeling avoiding this whole issue of updating the brand names in the cat table while from the users perspective they get to see the data in a table format as they want to see it. This is an exact use case for using a DB view.